# Can columnstore index reduce index creation time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table having around 130 million rows. I have created a Clustered index for the table which takes close to 1 hour to get created. How can I improve the process of index creation? Will column store index fare any better ? I have not tried it as the table is being used by others.Also, the table is partitioned into 63 partitions. I use SQL Sever 2016.

Comment: you could use execution plan with simple and common queries to monitor the performance of the query and the indexes, and determine which part needs improvements. just test it with queries that usually used against that table. Then, expand your testing with more in-depth queries that joins with other tables. Until you hit the jackpot!

Comment: As creating the index is a one-time thing (or *ought* to be, anyway), why is this time important? Whether or not creating a columnstore instead of a B-tree index is faster depends greatly on your data and your server hardware; don't believe anyone who tells you one will definitely be faster than the other. Testing is king. Note that Enterprise edition has an `ONLINE = ON` option to keep the table accessible while indexes are created (even for columnstores) but snapshotting the data can take a while, and eat plenty of disk space.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes usually it is a one time thing, but here in my case, each month, data has to be refreshed. A truncate and load procedure is followed here. So index creation has to be done each month. The index creation is taking more time than the actual data load itself.

Comment: For existing big tables, consider not bulk loading into a heap but already having the clustered index in place. SQL Server 2016 supports minimally logged bulk inserts into a clustered index (this required a trace flag in previous versions). I'm not sure about a columnstore, there are other [guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-data-loading-guidance) for those. On a bigly big table, this can well outpace first bulk importing into a heap and then creating indexes. (If there are non-clustered indexes, you may still want to delay those.)

Comment: Much of the advice in the [Data Loading Performance Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd425070) remains valid as-is, except the bits about trace flag 610 (which is obsolete and always on now). Note in particular that you can even do parallel bulk inserts into a clustered index. Even with an existing partitioned table, creating the new partition with an index can be faster than building the index afterwards.

Comment: @AsRa, unless you have other reasons for considering columnstore, try loading the table with (only) the clustered index in place as Jeroen suggested.

Comment: @DanGuzman and what if I want to reduce the execution time? Will column store help me achieve it? In which case is column store helpful?

Comment: @AsRa, columnstore is designed to improve performance of queries that perform large scans. The cost of building and/or maintaining a clustered columnstore is higher than that of a traditional clustered b-tree index so I suspect loading with a traditional clustered index in place will be faster. That said, columnstore may provide better query performance after creation depending on your workload. I suggest you first focus on the query performance and optimize the index creation separately. Data are usually read much more often than written.